# MAMP - php doesn't work when there is html code

Tags: php, html, mamp

Let me explain my situation.
I made a local website on Windows Using WAMP.
I transfered my files to a MACBOOK, and i installed MAMP

For some odd reason
When i submit a login form on Wamp, it shows me Blank page.
I searched the internet and i found that my login.php file has html code inside because its a template, and my mamp works only if i have only php code in the login.php file
For example:

THIS WAY IT WORKS:

```
<?php
 echo "Hello World";
?>
```

THIS DOES NOT WORK:

```
<html>
<head>
 HTML_CODE_FOR_WEBSITE_TEMPLATE
 </head>
 </html>
 <?php
 echo "hello world";
 ?>
```

Somehow mamp displays blank page because it thinks the code has errors
HOWEVER. the code is 100% working, because it works 100% on Windows

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your HTML doesn't have a `<body>` to show the message in. See http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/structure.html for an example what a HTML document should look like (it's HTML 4, but it doesn't really matter)

Comment: If you are satisfied with an answer, please accept it by clicking the check mark beside it. If not, please tell us what else you need. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>HTML CODE FOR WEBSITE TEMPLATE</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php echo "hello world"; ?>
</body>

</html>
```

This is HTML5. Remember, the difference isn't between "Mac" and "PC", necessarily. It's between BROWSERS. So you'd want to say something like "it works on Firefox (version 26) but not Safari (version xx.xx)", etc.